# Get entire dropdown list items into an array in InfoPath

Tags: c#, xpath, infopath

I have an InfoPath XSN form template with a dropdown list.  This is bound at design time to a data source and populated with a list of names when the form is loaded.

I would like to get hold of all of the names in this dropdown list into an array for processing elsewhere on that form.  I have tried to get hold of a reference to the dropdown list as below (and similar variations);

```
XPathNavigator myNav = this.MainDataSource.CreateNavigator();
object dd = myNav.Select("/dfs:myFields/dfs:queryFields/q:Site/@STitle", this.NamespaceManager).Current;
```

But I'm only getting the current value and not able to get hold of the entire list.  Any one able to help please?

Comment: Please provide example input to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach to the datasource you bound the listbox to (a secondary data source) the same way you are attaching to your primary.

```
XPathNavigator myNav = this.DataSources["datasourcename"].CreateNavigator();
```

Then just use the navigator to work with the fields/nodes as normal XML, so you can put them in array or just use the collection of nodes or whatever.

The MS documenation has some simple examples of connecting to a secondary data source and selecting nodes (among other things).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb509311(v=office.12).aspx